# When I change from tsx to jsx In next js , the design on the browser page changes

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, tsx

I am building a project using typescript for some files, for other files that were in tsx I changed them to jsx but the issue I am facing is that the design in the browser of that file changes! ,

I did not make any changes to the tailwind or CSS related to those files, its only  from the conversion of tsx to jsx (if I convert back to TSX the design will be okay again )

I am using Next js 14 and tailwind CSS

Comment: I am assuming you are converting parts of an existing project to TS because otherwise I would try to refrain from mixing JS & TS in the same project, but that's just my experience. 

Regarding your question, start by checking if you are getting the html classes properly. Is it the same exact strings as your other non-TS components? Did you try with 'non-custom' Taiwind classes? Try something like 'text-xl' and see if that works.

Comment: @EyalEizenberg I fixed that ,  the issues was not related directly to ts or js , but the problem was that my tailwind config only included ts and TSX files , and not js and jsx , 

Thank you for your help